# How to format date and time in angularjs with rails at backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I have a form in angularjs which inputs date and time.

```
<form novalidate class="simple-form" name="eventForm" ng-submit="save()">
    Date: <input type="date" ng-model="Event.date" /><br />
    Time: <input type="time" ng-model="Event.time" /><br />
    Venue: <input type="text" ng-model="Event.venue"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

I am using rails at backend, when I send this date and time to the rails controller, then it is not the same as my input. it is something else.below is my schema for events.

shema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20151005201646) do

  create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.date     "date"
    t.time     "time"
    t.text     "venue",      limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at",               null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",               null: false
  end

end
```

What i think the problem is that, the date and time format of angularjs is different from that of rails.so how to correct this error.

Comment: you can do it either on client or server... on server you can do it json.parse or on client you can use ngModel.$formatter